# Excel VBA to fill empty cells that satisfy condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find an excel VBA solution to the following problem,

I have a dataset in which some cells are empty and they need to be filled based on a condition. The condition is that it would be filled with station number corresponding to the one with a date range of +/- 5 days. Also, the lot number should match for these rows.

Please help!

For example please see the example in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, I just did it so try it and let us know if it work.
And don't forget to change the name with the one of your sheet in the third line.

```
Sub FillBlank()
    Dim F As Worksheet
    Set F = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")
    Dim i As Long: i = 0
    Dim j As Long
    Do While F.Range("D2").Offset(i, 0) <> ""
        If F.Range("A2").Offset(i, 0) = "" Then
            j = 0
            Do While F.Range("D2").Offset(j, 0) <> ""
                If (Abs(DateDiff("d", F.Range("D2").Offset(i, 0).Value, F.Range("D2").Offset(j, 0).Value)) <= 5) And (F.Range("C2").Offset(i, 0) = F.Range("C2").Offset(j, 0)) Then
                    F.Range("A2").Offset(i, 0) = F.Range("A2").Offset(j, 0).Value
                    GoTo Next_Blank
                End If
            j = j + 1
            Loop
        End If
Next_Blank:
    i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```